# Inject some preformatted html using webpack or custom extension for it

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Is there a way to inject the block of code below (as is, with the comments and string formation without it collapsing into one line) using just the `webpack`. Preferably, on a stage of building, that way generated files would have it injected.

```
<!-- Comment -->
<script>/* script goes here */</script>
<!-- End Commnet -->
```

I'm not sure from which side to approach as a webpack is kind new to me, except maybe some step by step configuration from their documentation.

I have been looking into `webpack-html-plugin`, but didn't found a way to specify a chunk as a string, as there is only files allowed.

I already found a way to inject it as a string (but only when react app is already running) using `insertAdjacentHTML`, but this is not what I looking for. I want to be able to pass arguments to `webpack` using its config files, but some of the arguments differs depending on the environment.

Comment: Hey Katherine, if the answer helped you, can you selected as the answer for your question?  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `html-webpack-plugin`

You can define any variables in your `webpack.config.js` including html:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    header: '<h1>A title</h1>',
    anyElement: '<b>I am an html element</b>'
})
```

Then you can insert them into your `index.html` like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.header %>
        <h1>Some Other Html Content</h1>
        <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.footer %>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you have external html files that you want to use you can do that by using the node js integrated module called `fs` to read the files and then pass the into your variables. You don't need to install `fs` as it comes with nodejs

```
let fs = require('fs');

const myFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/myfile.html');
const thatFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/thatfile.html');

module.exports = {

    // your config

    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        myFile: myFile,
        thatFile: thatFile,
      })
     ]
});
```

Now when you run Webpack your HTML file will be injected in the places you have specified.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.myFile %>
        <h1>Some other html content</h1>
        <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.yourFile %>
    </body>
</html>
```